# Serializing Enum to JSON in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Java `enum` where I store different statuses:

```
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active", "Active"),
    O("onboarding", "Onboarding"),
    NV("not_verified", "Not Verified"),
    V("verified", "Verified"),
    S("suspended", "Suspended"),
    I("inactive", "Inactive");

    @Getter
    private String shortName;

    @JsonValue
    @Getter
    private String fullName;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    // Use the fromStatus method as @JsonCreator
    @JsonCreator
    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String statusText) {
        for (BusinessCustomersStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.getShortName().equalsIgnoreCase(statusText)) {
                return status;
            }
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Unknown status: '%s'", statusText));
    }
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersStatus.java

The code works well when I want to get the list of items into pages for the value `fullName` because I use `@JsonValue` annotation.

I have a case where I need to get the `shortValue` for this code:

```
return businessCustomersService.findById(id).map( businessCustomers -> businessCustomersMapper.toFullDTO(businessCustomers));
```

Source: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/316c97aa5dc34488771ee11fb0dcf6dc1e4303da/src/main/java/org/merchant/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersRestServiceImpl.java#L77

But I get `fullValue`. Do you know for a single row how I can map the `shortValue`?

Comment: Spring Pageable query params are `?page=0&size=100&sort=id,DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend serializing it as an object. This can be done via the `@JsonFormat` annotation at the class level:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active", "Active"),
    O("onboarding", "Onboarding"),
//...

    @Getter
    private String shortName;

    @Getter
    private String fullName;
//...
```

This will lead to the following result when serializing this enum for `BusinessCustomersStatus.A`:

```
{"shortName":"active","fullName":"Active"}
```

Alternatively, you could define `status` field as `String`:

```
public class BusinessCustomersFullDTO {

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String businessType;

    private String status;
}
```

and map its value like this:

```
businessCustomersFullDTO.status(businessCustomers.getStatus().getShortName());
```

Comment: One additional question: I have a case then I want to return form API `https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/dto/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersFullDTO.java` witch will hold `fullname` and `BusinessCustomersDTO` which will contain `shortName` in that case how I can modify the code?

Comment: You can use a `String`  field named status on both DTOs and map its value as appropriate: `businessCustomersFullDTO.status(businessCustomers.getStatus().getShortName());` or `businessCustomersDTO.status(businessCustomers.getStatus().getFullName());`